# str_ireplace does not work with non ASCII charecters

Tags: php, regex, search

I need to highlight search result in text in Russian, but str_ireplace() just does not work when query has different case. I've tried everything that I've fould in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php), but nothing works. Here what I have tried:

```
<?php
setlocale (LC_ALL, 'ru_RU');
$query = 'ПрОбЛеМа';
$result = 'Эта проблема нам не знакома.';

$result = str_ireplace($query, "<strong>$query</strong>", $result); // does not work
$result = preg_replace("/($query)/i", '<strong>$1</strong>', $result); // does not work
$result = mb_eregi_replace("$query", "<strong>$query</strong>", $result); // does not work
$result = ext_str_ireplace($query, "<strong>$query</strong>", $result); // from php.net - does not work
$result = highlightStr($result, $query); // from php.net - does not work

?>
```

Is there any way to make it work? I'm getting desperate here.

PHP 5.3.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add the "u" (unicode) modifier to preg_replace, it should work:

```
 $result = preg_replace("/(".preg_quote($query).")/iu", '<strong>$1</strong>', $result);
```

Also, you need to quote special characters in a regex pattern.

Comment: OMG, this is genius! How I want to buy you a beer for that!

Comment: Nice guessing, given that non-ASCII does not automatically imply Unicode ;-)

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario, guess I grew up in the world full of sunshine, where non-ASCII means Unicode by default. My fault not to mention it :)

Answer (score 3):

you can use mb_eregi_replace, if you use non ASCII/multi Byte

but remove the "

```
$result = mb_eregi_replace($query, "<strong>$query</strong>", $result);
```

you also can set your encoding:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
mb_regex_encoding("UTF-8");
```

Comment: how without regular expressions to solve this problem y?

Provided that the Register of characters in the line of a pointer can not be changed (!).

Answer (score 1):

Drop in replacement:

```
function mb_str_ireplace ($search, $replace, $subject, &$replacements) 
{
    return preg_replace("/$search/ui", $replace, $subject, -1, $replacements);
}
```