# str_ireplace() does not catch uppercase in Cyrillic script

Tags: php, non-ascii-characters, cyrillic

[image]I am using this function to color all the matches in my search. It works on lowercase words, in Cyrillic script, like "search" but not with "Search".

The function:

```
public function highlight($text='', $word='')
    {
        if(strlen($text) > 0 && strlen($word) > 0)
        {
            return (str_ireplace($word, "<span class='highlights'><strong>" . $word . "</strong></span>", $text));
        }
        return $text;
    }
```

I've been thinking about it but I don't know how I should change it, to make it work. Can you give me advice? Thank you in advance!

Comment: i try but your code working properly. Please explain with example.

Comment: I've added a picture :) Word, that starts with uppercase, can't be colored.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [str\_ireplace does not work with non ASCII charecters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221947/str-ireplace-does-not-work-with-non-ascii-charecters)

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44626512/4265352) on a similar question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [str\_ireplace works as str\_replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44625860/str-ireplace-works-as-str-replace)